# Copy specific column from table to table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, copy

Copy specific column from *Table Student* with column `id`, `name`, `address`, `school`, `age`, `major`  to Table A but only column `id`, `name` and `age`

```
public function student()
{

    Transaksi::create([
        'id_' => $request->id,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'age' => $request->age
    ]);
```

}

but it did not work.

any better suggest

I'm using Laravel 8.6 and MySql.

Comment: did you add $fillable property to your Transaksi model?

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas nope because `table A` is copy from table `student`.

Comment: you are doing a mass assignment so you have to use $fillable property to your model. Laravel doesn't care whether you are copying or not. If you are doing mass assignments you should use $fillable property.

Comment: btw did you get any exceptions?

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas okay, I'm understand. So what I should do to change to be not `$fillable`

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas it nothing happen and don't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$student_column  = StudentModel::where('id', $specific_id)->get()[0];
$table_a_data = new TableAModel;
$table_a_data->student_id = $student_column->id;
$table_a_data->name = $student_column->name;
$table_a_data->age = $student_column->age;
$table_a_data->save();
```

Note that you should be referencing the student_id on Table A on the migrations so you should look to your migration file for Table A and add a column called student_id, you can add it as follow

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('student_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: I was do Migration so have to rollback migration?

Comment: you can do this to remigrate a specific table for a change
 
`php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/Migration_File_Name.php`

Comment: I'm prefer using `string` for `(student_id)` is allowed?

Comment: nope it has to be unsigned , and referenced to the other table, but don't worry it is the best practice

Comment: And yes you have to make name and age `$fillable` but do never make key id for a table `$fillable`

Comment: I'm prefer for now is not `$fillable`

I just add and there is possible to run atomatically?

Comment: this not solved because I want to change method.
Thank you for your help and advice.

Comment: I still can help you. ask anytime. i just need to see the full process. Thanks

Comment: I'll create new because will be missing if discuss in here.
Thank you for your help, I'm so appreciate

Comment: Alright good luck, thanks .

Comment: I hope you can still to join discuss in new forum I'll give the link

Comment: Sure! I would love

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388042/replicate-or-copy-table-to-table-using-laravel we can discuss in here

Answer (score 0):

> Mass assignment is a process of sending an array of data that will be
> saved to the specified model at once. But it may be vulnerable.
> $fillable property helps us to protect which fields we want to
> actually allow for creating or updating.

In your `Transaksi.php` file add:

```
protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'age'];
```